# Calling a method in server side in the change event of a checkbox JSP

Tags: jquery, jsp

I am using jquery for doing this example.
I have my checkbox declare

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="checkbox1" />

<script>
  $('#checkbox1').change(function() {
  if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
         <% call the jave method %>
  }
else
{
  <%call the java method%>
}
</script>
```

The problem consist that when the page is loading the two actions are evaluated. I was thinking in using ajax but haven't found one example for check box change events.

Comment: You won't be able to call code between <% %> because JSP is rendered server side, the only way to call something server side is to make a new HTTP request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hummm ... your code seems good, but to avoid the bord effect at page load, what do you think about using the `$('#checkbox1').click()` event instead of change ? 
The page load will not fire click event, like this you're already sure that the action come from your user.
Don't forget to check the `checked attribute` like you already do and i think you're right.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript code runs on the client (web browser), while java code runs on the server (servlet). They run *on different machines*. This is what your confusion is all about: they don't run next to each other. You should wore java in this context as a means of getting HTTP request, processing something on server, and sending back HTTP response. All in all, java code is to be executed during what's referred to as 'server-side processing' above.

Effectively, what you *want* to do is to fire an AJAX request on some JS event, do whatever you want in servlet and do some action with the returned data in a callback function.

You need to do some research to find out how to do that. As you seem to be using jQuery, [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) is a good starting place.